# Why webP image takes longer time in painting then jpeg?

Tags: performance, jpeg, webp

I wanted to compare the rendering speed for webp and jpeg photos, so I tested it in chrome. Here is the result: Rendering time is less for webp and more time for painting. In the case of jpeg, painting takes less time, but idle time is long.
In the case of webP, it seems that it took more time for painting because it is lossless, but I don't know exactly. Can you explain why it came out like this? Thanks

[Webp performance](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0FjQ9.png).  [Jpeg performance](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eTo0Q.png)

I used test for chrome dev tool performance.

1. What exactly does painting time mean?
2. What exactly does idle time mean?
3. WebP took less total time, so is webP loading faster?